# DCM flyback converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, flyback

Recently,my research will focus on DCM flybck but I don't have any theory on DCM. I don't know how to start I want to model the small signal model.

Do you guys can suggest me some paper or book let me can learn form it. I will be appreciate it.

I have searched some papers but it doesn't teach me the basic so I have no idea.

Comment: What you can’t find anything or don’t understand it? https://www.vishay.com/docs/71180/71180.pdf

Comment: You can start with my seminar [The Dark Side of the Flyback Converter](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202011.pdf) and carry on with my two other seminars dedicated to small-signal modeling (APEC [2013](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202013.pdf), [2014](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202014.pdf)). The key is to use the PWM switch model operated in DCM and place the model in your flyback circuit.

Comment: Do you understand how a boost converter works?

Comment: @VerbalKint Ok, your semimars are very useful for me

Comment: @Andyaka I understand it

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks

Comment: @Jitter456 do you understand an inverting buck-boost converter like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/euyJQ.png

Comment: @Andyaka No, I need to understand this first?

Comment: If you look at the inverting buck-boost, and understand it first, then you are a simple step from understanding the flyback converter. Call it a step along the way. In fact, Chris Basso's seminar (provided by @VerbalKint whom I believe knows Mister Basso quite well) says precisely the same thing.

Comment: @VerbalKint Most people use State-Space Averaging Method but your seminars used PWM switch model because can't model the DCM ?

Comment: @Andyaka OK I will try to understand it first

Comment: This [Q/A](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276436) might help from another site.

Comment: @Jitter456, the state-space averaging technique (SSA) is a technique introduced by Dr. Cuk in 1976 and was a solution at the time to determine the control-to-output transfer function of switching converters. The SSA requires heavy matrices manipulations and first goes through the drawing of an equivalent model before running harmonic analysis. Furthermore, it fails to predict the RHP zero presence in DCM. The PWM switch model (1986) is, in my opinion, better suited for switching power supplies analysis and I recommend you study its principle. I made many models in CCM, DCM, QR etc.

Comment: @VerbalKint But the PWM switching model just for the Two switch device right? Can this method use in the three phase inverter ?

Comment: @Jitter456, yes, this is for a two-switch approach but a 4-switch full-bridge circuit for instance is still a buck-derived topology and can be modeled with the PWM switch. For 3-phase inverter, it may not be well adapter though.